# Convert jQuery Array string to PHP Array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, foreach

First of all, I gotta say I'm pretty new to PHP and I'm trying to get a PHP object on which I can use foreach.

The following string is passed through $.ajax(); I'm trying to turn the following string:

```
$menu = "[
 {"title" : TEST1, "href" : #},
 {"title" : TEST2, "href" : QWERTY},
 {"title" : TEST3, "href" : QWERTY, "active" : 1}
]"
```

into and php object on which I can use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($menu as $li){
    echo $li['title'];
}
```

Am I using the optimal solution for creating the menu items or should I be following another format?

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards,
Alex G.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a JSON format.. and it is broken.. Fix your JSON data as shown and loop using a `foreach`

**PHP**

```
<?php
$menu = '[{"title" : "TEST1", "href" : "#"},
 {"title" : "TEST2", "href" : "QWERTY"},
 {"title" : "TEST3", "href" : "QWERTY", "active" : 1}]';

foreach(json_decode($menu,true) as $k=>$arr)
{
    echo $arr['title']."<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
TEST1
TEST2
TEST3
```

Comment: I tried json_decode already and it wasn't working. Thank you very much, putting the QUOTES seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `json_decode` function

```
<?php

       $menu = '[
 {"title" : TEST1, "href" : #},
 {"title" : TEST2, "href" : QWERTY},
 {"title" : TEST3, "href" : QWERTY, "active" : 1}
]';
    $test=json_decode($menu );
   print_r($test);
   foreach($test as $ts)
   {
       echo $ts['title'];
       echo "<br>";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Should I be setting TEST1, TEST2, etc. as the "TEST1" string in jquery?

Comment: @GrozavAlexIoan Look that string is in JSON format.

Comment: You used double quotes without character escape

Comment: @Let'sCode :- Hey that string is broken. refer `Shankar Damodaran's answer`.